# Text and video on a glass/window

Tags: animation

I am a beginner Unity-user, and interested in high-tech thems.
So I'm looking to make a high-tech futuristic gaming-room in HDRP. I'm therefore looking to do some effect on my window in the room. The plan was to make it so that I can turn it on/off, show a movie, and show text changing all the time. No need for interaction with the windows, but more like an animation on a transparent surface. Is this something an n00b can possibly make, or is it really complex?

Comment: same question is [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98557/glass-material-for-unity-5)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you display a video on any 3D surface at all? Have you tried changing that surface's material to make it look how you want ?